# Laravel Image Intevention image "cannot be displayed"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, imagick

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    $image = Image::make(file_get_contents($imagepath));
    return = Response::make($image, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'image/jpg']);
});
```

Using Image Intervention with the above code, I am just getting a message at /test "The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

This is on a XAMPP environment with both GD and Imagick enabled.

If I output dd($image) I get an object that is empty:

```
object(Intervention\Image\Image)#393 (9) { ["driver":protected]=> object(Intervention\Image\Imagick\Driver)#394 (2) { ["decoder"]=> object(Intervention\Image\Imagick\Decoder)#395 (1) { ["data":"Intervention\Image\AbstractDecoder":private]=> NULL } ["encoder"]=> object(Intervention\Image\Imagick\Encoder)#396 (4) { ["result"]=> NULL ["image"]=> NULL ["format"]=> NULL ["quality"]=> NULL } } ["core":protected]=> object(Imagick)#392 (0) { } ["backups":protected]=> array(0) { } ["encoded"]=> string(0) "" ["mime"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["dirname"]=> NULL ["basename"]=> NULL ["extension"]=> NULL ["filename"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: Where is `$imagepath` defined?

Comment: You don't have to use `file_get_contents` function. Just pass the image path directly to Intervention. Also there is a syntax error. No `=` after `return`. And instead of direct reference of `$image` variable, use `$image->encode('jpg')` to be specific.

Comment: Thank you, Hakan. Removing file_get_contents and adding $image->encode('jpg') did the trick.